# JMeter - Uploaded image is corrupt because the Post data is included in the uploaded image

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

On JMeter 5.4.1, I am using "Files Upload" tab in the HTTP Request. I tried using/not using different options such as Multipart/form-data, Browser-compatible headers. I also tried Content-encoding empty or UTF-8. But no matter what, the image file gets corrupt because the following info is posted in the image file itself. I opened the JPG file in Notepad++ to see why the file was corrupt. When I post the same image using Postman, the following info is not posted in the image file and therefore it's not corrupt.

At the beginning of the image file:

```
--jjQWVOxqJaZTsBs1jSov0eEMj80BfocR3eh
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="A"; filename="Image1.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
```

At the end of the image file:

```
--jjQWVOxqJaZTsBs1jSov0eEMj80BfocR3eh--
```

The above is the same info that I can see in the Request Body of View Results Tree as Post data, although this info was provided in "Files Upload" tab only.[image: Top part of image file is getting unwanted info from JMeter]

Answer (score 0):

> I tried using/not using different options such as Multipart/form-data, Browser-compatible headers. I also tried Content-encoding empty or UTF-8.

this is not something you should be doing. Your job is very simple - send the same request as browser (or Postman) does.

The easiest way of doing this is just recording the request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

And the only small extra think you need to take care of is to copy the file(s) you will be uploading to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation prior to making the request, this way JMeter will generate proper [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager).

More information: [JMeter Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-testing)

Comment: I am using API requests and cannot record. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Out of interest why you "cannot record" API requests? It's more than possible if they use HTTP or HTTPS as the transport

Comment: I should have clarified better, than saying cannot record. I have more than 100 different photos that I need to upload. When I record Postman traffic in JMeter, the whole image file is recorded under Body Data instead of Files Upload. If it was on Files Upload, I could parameterize the file names, but if I can't really do that if I am sending a bunch of non-characters in the Body Data.